# GUI Ethereum just closes and does not import presale JSON wallet

Tags: wallets, presale

When I try to import presale JSON wallet using the Ethereum GUI just closes (Kind of crashes) and does not import, has anyone seen this?

It appears the password is good I have checked the eth address and it shows the amount of ether I expect.

So I can't import my presale ethereum seed wallet. Has anyone fixed it and how to continue?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue right now.

Comment: Might be a bug. [Parity](https://parity.io) also supports presale wallets. (Note, I work for parity, but if Ethereum Wallet is temporary unavailable, you should give this a try.)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to use the Ethereum wallet I tried on my mac and PC. I upgraded mist and ethereum wallet sync'ed nodes. Nothing worked. As a last resort I used   https://www.myetherwallet.com   it worked like a charm and I was able to transfer my ether to a safe exchange (Safe enough).
If you do this then make sure you first test opening a small wallet (a backup for example of a UTC-xxxxxxxxxxxx  file) with a small amount of ether $5 worth and test the transfer to your target (exchange) so there are no surprises for you when you do the presale wallet work. Do your due diligence and a ton of homework so you know what you're doing. loosing your ether is a nightmare I would not have been able to wake from. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, Maybe Parity would work as well. Like I said do your due diligence, thanks for your suggestion 5chdn.